# Meaning of the word "FOR" used at the beginning of a sentence

Tags: meaning, conjunctions

I have encountered the word *for* many times. But, even if I use the dictionary, I can not understand the meaning of this word used at the beginning of a sentence.

Here is an example:

> It would be an excellent match. For he was rich and she was handsome.

Does it always mean *because*?

Comment: No, _for_ doesn't "always" mean because. For example: _It would be an excellent match – for a little while, at least._

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. If *for* is followed by a *finite* clause (a clause headed by a tensed verbform), it means *because*, as in your example:

   > <sup>?</sup> For he **was** rich and she **was** handsome.

   This is, by the way, only marginally acceptable in formal writing, since *for* acts to subordinate the clause which follows it, just as *because* does. You can get away with it if the register you are working in tolerates sentence fragments, but otherwise your example would be better pointed with a comma:

   > <sup>ok</sup>It would be an excellent match, for he was rich and she was handsome.

   Note that unlike a *because* clause, a *for* clause of this sort cannot in Modern English precede the matrix clause which it modifies:

   > <sup>∗</sup> For he was rich and she was handsome, it would be an excellent match.
2. If *for* is followed by an NP (a phrase headed by, and acting as, a noun), *for* is a preposition and the NP is its object. Together they comprise a preposition phrase, which may stand at the beginning of a sentence:

   > For most people, this would be an excellent match.
3. If *for* is followed by a non-finite clause headed by a *marked infinitive* (*to + VERB<sup>INF</sup>*), it acts as a complementizer, marking the clause which follows it as an argument of the verb in the matrix clause; if it lies at the beginning of a sentence that clause will normally act as the subject of the verb in the governing clause:

   > For these two **to marry** would be an excellent match.

   Such *for ... to* clauses may also act as the object of a verb, noun, adjective or adverb, but in these cases *for* will not lie at the beginning of the sentence:

   > He was eager for these two **to marry**.
   >   We saw little opportunity for these two **to marry**.

---

<sup>∗</sup> indicates that the following utterance is unacceptable.
<sup>?</sup> indicates that the following utterance is in some cases unacceptable.